# Laravel background-image:url is returning 1

Tags: php, laravel, assets, laravel-blade

I'm making a webapplication in Laravel. I have the following code snippet:

```
<div class="user-info" style="background-image:url({{ asset(Auth::user()->partner->background) or '/images/default/background1.jpg'}})">
```

This is the result in the HTML:

```
<div class="user-info" style="background-image:url(1)">
```

What I'm supposed to get is the following from the database:

```
images/backgrounds/HRVl7TXkAxlhASj14vAV.png
```

This is weird because if I do the following:

```
{{dd(Auth::user()->partner->background)}}
```

it does actually `dd()` the filename `images/backgrounds/HRVl7TXkAxlhASj14vAV.png` from the database. Why does it echo 1 istead of the filename when I put it in a background-image:url?

Comment: Did you try doing it without `asset()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
{!! "'".asset(Auth::user()->partner->background)."'" or '/images/default/background1.jpg'!!}
```

**EDIT**

A bit messy, but should work

```
{!! Auth::user()->partner && Auth::user()->partner->background ? "'".asset(Auth::user()->partner->background)."'" : '/images/default/background1.jpg' !!}
```

I recommend you to write separate method in User for this feature.
Something like this:

```
public function background()
{
    // your awesome logic
    return $pathToBackground;
}
```

and then:

```
<div class="user-info" style="background-image:url('{!! asset(Auth::user()->background()) !!}');" >
```

Comment: This made it work for me. However, if the partner is null and I try to get the background from a null object I still get the null object reference exception (even though I'm using the `or`). I got it working using your solution with the old `isset($x) ? true : false` type of code. Any idea how to get this working using the `or` thing?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   <div class="user-info" style="background-image:url({{ asset(($background=Auth::user()->partner->background) ? $background :'/images/default/background1.jpg' )}})">
```